# How to view content of Cache in JCache

Tags: hazelcast, jcache

There are options to read the cache by using keys. Like this :

```
   Collection<Integer> userIds = context.getUserDao().allUserIds();  
   for (Integer userId : userIds) {
        User user = cache.getUserCache().get(userId);
        System.out.println(user.toString());
    }
```

With the latter it will load the expired ones to the cache and then display it.

But the requirement is to view all the content currently in the cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how to view all the content of the Cache. Found the method after going through the Java Docs of JCache.

```
public void printAllCache(){

    Cache<String, String> cache = cacheManager.getCache(CACHENAME, String.class, String.class);

    Iterator<Cache.Entry<String,String>> allCacheEntries= cache.iterator();
    while(allCacheEntries.hasNext()){
        Cache.Entry<String,String> currentEntry = allCacheEntries.next();
        System.out.println("Key: "+currentEntry.getKey()+" Value: "+ currentEntry.getValue());
    }
    return returnProperties;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the following link is of help
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/jcache_basic.htm#COHDG5812

Comment: This only gives the way to get data for known keys. What I want to know is getting all the content of the cache without knowing the keys.